# Is $L = \{xw^3x^{rev}\mid x, w\in\{0, 1\}^*\}$ context-free?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, formal-grammars

The title pretty much explains the question, but still: Is the language
$$L = \{xw^3x^{rev}\mid x, w\in\{0, 1\}^*\}$$
context-free?

I think it isn't and would motivate that suspicion by the following reasoning:
if we consider the two languages:
$$L' = \{xwx^{rev} \mid\ x,w\in\{0, 1\}^*\} \text{ which is context-free}$$
$$L'' = \{w^3\mid w\in\{0, 1\}^*\} \text{ which can be shown to be non-context-free by the pumping lemma}$$
Now if $L''$ were context-free, then we could obtain the initial language $L$ by "enclosing" $L''$ with $L'$, i.e. $L'$ is sort of a sub-language of $L''$. We can do that by extending the eventual CFG of $L'$ (let's assume its starting non-terminal is $S'$) with the following productions:
$$S'' \to 0S''0 \,\mid\, 1S''1 \,\mid\, S'$$
and thus obtaining a grammar for $L$ whose starting symbol is $S''$.

The only problem is that I'm not sure how to formalize that idea and if it's even right and enough to prove that $L$ isn't context-free. Any ideas are welcome! Many thanks in advance!

Comment: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/18524/755

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use closure properties to formalize your intuitions.

Context-free languages are closed under intersection with regular languages. In this case you can go from $L$ to (a language close to) $L''$ by observing that the string $xx^{rev}$ has the same first and last letter.

Comment: I also tried finding such an approach and your answer validates that idea, but I can't see it... Could you hint more? How could we go from L to L'' by intersecting with a regular language... Only thing I can think of is interesecting with $1\sum^*0\cup0\sum^*1$, i.e. the language of all words with different first and last character, but that would also restrict the possibilities of $w^3$ in the middle...

Comment: Ooooh, now I see, so the actual "close to L'' " language would be $w^3$ but where w starts and ends with different characters, which we can again show by the pumping lemma is not context-free, right? ^^

Comment: @D.Petrov Yes, that is what I think will work.

Comment: Confirmed, I also checked it out, everything seems super duper fine! Thank you a lot!